# awk to change the record separator (RS) to every 2 lines

Tags: bash, command-line, awk

I am wondering how to use Awk to process every 2 lines of data instead of every one.  By default the record separator (RS) is set to every new line, how can I change this to every 2 lines.

Answer (score 6):

It depends of what you want to achieve, but one way is to use the `getline` instruction. For each line, read next one and save it in a variable. So you will have first line in `$0` and second one in `even_line`:

```
getline even_line
```

Answer (score 5):

Divide&Conquer: do it in two steps:

1. use awk to introduce blank line
   to separate each two-line record: `NR%2==0 {print ""}`
2. pipe to another awk process and
   set record separator to blank line: `BEGIN {RS=""}`

Advantage: In the second `awk` process you have all fields of the two lines accessible as `$1 to $NF`.

```
awk '{print}; NR%2==0 {print ""}' data | \
awk 'BEGIN {RS=""}; {$1=$1;print}'
```

Note:
`$1=$1` is used here to enforce an update on `$0` (the whole record).
This guaranties that the output prints the two-line record on one line.
Once you modify a field in your program when you process the two-line records this is no longer required.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to merge lines, use the [`paste`](http://man.cx/paste) utility:

```
$ printf "%s\n" one two three four five
one
two
three
four
five

$ printf "%s\n" one two three four five | paste -d " " - -
one two
three four
five
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit hackish, but it's a literal answer to your question:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = "[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n"} {$0 = RT; print $1, $NF}' inputfile
```

Set the record separator to a regex which matches two lines. Then for each line, set `$0` to the record terminator (which is what matched the regex in `RS`). This performs field splitting on `FS`. The print statement is just a demonstration place holder.

Note that `$0` will contain two newlines, but the fields will not contain any newlines.

Comment: Very useful, I think!