# bash scripting how convert log with key into csv

Tags: bash, csv

I have a log with format like a table

```
ge-1/0/0.0              up    down inet     10.100.100.1/24 
                                   multiservice
ge-1/0/2.107            up    up   inet     10.187.132.193/27
                                            10.187.132.194/27
                                   multiservice
ge-1/1/4                up    up  
ge-1/1/5.0              up    up   inet     10.164.69.209/30
                                   iso     
                                   mpls    
                                   multiservice
```

how we convert it to format csv like below:

```
ge-1/0/0.0,up,down,inet|multiservice,10.100.100.1/24
ge-1/0/2.107,up,up,inet|multiservice,"10.187.132.193/27,10.187.132.194/27"
ge-1/1/4,up,up
ge-1/1/5.0,up,up,inet|iso|mpls|multiservice,10.164.69.209/30
```

I've tried with grep interfacename -A4 but it's display other interface information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

show() {
    [ "$ge" ] || return
    [ "$add_quotes" ] && iprange="\"$iprange\""
    out="$ge,$upd1,$upd2,$service,$iprange"
    out="${out%%,}"
    echo "${out%%,}"
}

while read line
do 
    case "$line" in
        ge*)
            show
            read ge upd1 upd2 service iprange < <( echo "$line" )
            add_quotes=
            ;;
        [0-9]*)
            iprange="$iprange,$line"
            add_quotes=Y
            ;;
        *) 
            service="$service|$line"
            ;;
    esac
done

# Show last line
show
```

With your sample data provided as stdin, this script returns:

```
ge-1/0/0.0,up,down,inet|multiservice,10.100.100.1/24
ge-1/0/2.107,up,up,inet|multiservice,"10.187.132.193/27,10.187.132.194/27"
ge-1/1/4,up,up
ge-1/1/5.0,up,up,inet|iso|mpls|multiservice,10.164.69.209/30
```

**How it works:**  This script reads from stdin line by line (`while read line`).  Each line is then classified into one of three types: (a) a new record (i.e. a line that starts with "ge-"), (b) a continuation record that provides another IP range (i.e. a record that starts with a number), or (c) a continuation line that provides another service (i.e. a record that starts with a letter).  Taking these cases in turn:

(a)  When the line contains the start of a new record, that means that the previous record has ended, so we print it out with the `show` function.  Then we read from the new line the five columns that I have named: ge upd1 upd2 service iprange.  And, we reset the add_quotes variable to empty.

(b)  When the line contains just another IP range, we add that to the current IP range.  As per the example in the question, combinations of two or more IP ranges are separated by a comma and enclosed in quotes.  Thus, we set `add_quotes` to "Y".

(c)  When the line contains an additional service, we add that to the service variable.  As per the example in the question, two services are separated by a vertical bar "|" and no quotes are used.

The function `show` first checks to make sure that there is a record to show by checking that the `ge` variable is non-empty. If it is empty, then the `return` statement is executed so that the function exits (returns) without processing any of its further statements.  If `$ge` was non-empty, the function proceeds to the next statement which adds quotes around the IP range variable if they are needed.  It then combines the variables with commas separating them, removes trailing commas (as per the example in the question), and sends the result to stdout.

Comment: asically what I got, this script try to fetch line by line and when its meet ge* interface it will process, and also for ip address [0-9].can you explain why we use add_quotes=Y?

Comment: I have added a long explanation.  As for the decision to add quotes around the IP ranges, it is just following the example output in the question: there are no quotes around IP ranges __except__ when two IP ranges have been combined together with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

### parselog.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    RS = "[^\n]*\n( [^\n]*\n)*"
    OFS = ","
}

length(RT) > 0 {
    $0 = RT     # See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11917783/27581

    opts = ""
    ips = ""
    for (i = 4; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if (isIP($i)) {
            ips = append(ips, $i, ",")
        } else {
            opts = append(opts, $i, "|")
        }
    }
    print $1, $2, $3, opts, "\"" ips "\""
}

function isIP(str) {
    return str ~ /^[0-9]/
}

function append(list, val, separator) {
    if (length(list) > 0) {
        list = list separator
    }
    return list val
}
```

### Usage

```
$ ./parselog.awk < log.txt 
ge-1/0/0.0,up,down,inet|multiservice,"10.100.100.1/24"
ge-1/0/2.107,up,up,inet|multiservice,"10.187.132.193/27,10.187.132.194/27"
ge-1/1/4,up,up,,""
ge-1/1/5.0,up,up,inet|iso|mpls|multiservice,"10.164.69.209/30"
```