# awk multiple lines stored into variable

Tags: awk, multiline

Goodday,

I have a file in the following format :

```
XXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYAAAAAAAA
XXXXXXXXXXXIIIIIIII22222222
XXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPP
XXXXXXXXXXXAAAAAAAAKKKKKKKK
YYYYYYYYYYY22222222AAAAAAAA
YYYYYYYYYYY55555555BBBBBBBB
YYYYYYYYYYYGGGGGGGGKKKKKKKK
YYYYYYYYYYYQQQQQQQQ88888888
```

... and so on. Every 4 lines the first part (X, Y, ...) remains the same, the rest of the line changes. There is no separator between the lines, and the file is quite big.

I would like to find a way to use awk to read 4 lines at a time, store them in 4 variables  and/or set the RS to \n and the FS to something, because i would like to do comparisons in specific 4line-blocks.And be able to output all 4 lines on a match

i.e, If `substr(17,3) == X` output all 4 records you read.

My apologies for not supplying code, but I really have no idea how to do this with awk.

Given a specific number, ie Y=17, the script would be looking that to a given substring of each record. For example :

```
if (subst(11:2) == 17) then    # This can be a match on any line of a 4 grouping ( ie X... ) 
print (all 4 lines - All X...) - or print a given substring of those lines.
```

actual example with the sample provided

```
if (substr($0,21,2) == "PP") { print all 4 lines in memory }

...and it would print :

XXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYAAAAAAAA
XXXXXXXXXXXIIIIIIII22222222
XXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPP
XXXXXXXXXXXAAAAAAAAKKKKKKKK
```

Comment: how will you try to do comparisons? Something like `line1=="a" && line2=="b"` etc? You may give us a hint on how you want to work on this, otherwise it is a bit broad. Also, related [awk to change the record separator (RS) to every 2 lines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11913622/1983854).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following simple script should hopefully be useful at least as a start.

```
awk 'substr($0,21,2) == "PP" { p=1 } # remember match
    NR % 4 { a[NR%4] = $0; next }  # collect lines a[1] through a[3]
    # We have read four lines, and are ready to print if there was a match
    p { for (i=1; i<4; ++i) print a[i]; print $0;
        # reset for next iteration
        p=0 }' filename
```

The first condition is tested on all input lines.  If there is a match on any of them, we remember this by setting the flag variable `p` to 1 (anything non-zero will do, really).  The condition could be a regex just as well; `/^.{20}PP/` looks for "PP" in the 21st position.

The second condition fires on lines which are not multiples of 4.  We simply collect these lines, and (by way of the `next` statement) skip the remainder of the script.  (As you probably know, the `%` modulo operator calculates the remainder from division; so it goes from 1 to 3 and then cycles 0, 1, 2, ...)

Thus, if we fall through to the third condition, it means we are on a line whose line number is divisible by 4; now, the condition examines the value of `p`, and if it's nonzero, the action is taken.

(If it's zero, we fall through without printing anything, and the cycle starts over with `NR%4` equal to 1.)

Comment: Nice! According to the updated question, you may want to loop through the values and do a string comparison against 17 or whatever.

Comment: @fedorqui Updated as per your suggestion. In some ways, my original answer was better; but hope this helps.

Comment: Mmm I don't really know what the OP wants, but I would've looped through `a[]` and check for `substr()` on every single element: `for (...) if (substr ()) flag=1`and then print the full block later on if the flag is set. But, again, just wondering what is the actual goal here.

Comment: I gave a better output sample, your little bit of code has been really helpful already, it just applies the check on the last of every set of 4, i need a way to implement that for any line in a given set of 4. Still new to awk, so forgive me if this all sounds base.

Comment: Updated again.  Hope this helps some more.

Comment: I made it work with some tinkering, your post was really helpful, thank you.