# awk - cannot open file error

Tags: file, awk

```
#!/usr/bin/nawk -f

# Before lines are processed
BEGIN {

print "Awk Started" >> FILE_STDOUT

# Variables
rec1=""
rec2=""
rec3=""
rec4=""
mod=0
X=23

}

 NR % 5 != 0 {
 mod=NR%5
if (mod==1) 
    rec1=$0
else
if (mod=2)    
    rec2=$0
else
if (mod=3)   
    rec3=$0
else 
if (mod=4)  
  rec4=$0

next
}

# NR % 5 == 0
{

  if (substr($rec1,9,2)==X || substr($rec2,9,2)==X || substr($rec3,9,2)==X || substr($rec4,9,2)==X)
{
   print rec1
   print rec2
   print rec3
   print rec4
}
}

END {

   print "Awk Ended" >> FILE_STDOUT

}
```

While running the above script which is supposed to check blocks of 4 for a specific entry and output them, i get this error :

> awk: cannot open "" for output (No such file or directory)

What's the reason?

Sample input :

```
    101010201231000
    101010201AA1000
    101010201AA1000
    101010201AA1000
    303030401AA1000
    303030401321000
    303030401AA1000
    303030401AA1000
    505050601AA1000
    505050601AA1000
    505050601431000
    505050601AA1000
    707070801AA1000
    707070801AA1000
    707070801AA1000
    707070801561000
```

Sample output :

```
101010201231000
101010201AA1000
101010201AA1000
101010201AA1000
```

The error i am given is :

nawk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
        FILENAME="awktestor.txt" FNR=1 NR=1

Comment: It would  also be interesting to know what is the final goal of this program, because we may be able to find a more straight-forward approach.

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

```
print "Awk Started" >> FILE_STDOUT
```

you are redirecting the `print` output to a file, whose value is stored in the variable `FILE_STDOUT`. However, if this variable is not set, `awk` cannot redirect and it fails.

It is as if you would say:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print 1>>FILE_STDOUT}'
```

Which returns

> awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: expression for `>>' redirection has null
>   string value

---

Also, it seems to be that you want to match a line when `23` is found in the 10th and 11th character. Then, print that line together with the following 3 lines.

For that you can say:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^.{9}23/ {c=4} c&&c--' file
    101010201231000
    101010201AA1000
    101010201AA1000
    101010201AA1000
```

Comment: Thanks, i removed that during testing but then i got this :
nawk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
        FILENAME="awktestor.txt" FNR=5 NR=5 ------ On a 100 line file, that doesnt seem normal.

Comment: @onlyf this is completely new problem. It happens when you have so many fields in a line. What about updating your awk version? What system are you working on?

Comment: The line actually has one field, i ll edit with some examples one moment

Comment: @onlyf could it be that the file has some line problems? Check it with `cat -vet file` because it may happen that `awk` considers all lines as a single one.

Comment: Its not necessary that it will be the following 3 lines, 23 could be find in any of 4 lines.

Comment: @onlyf in fact you are looking for what [triplee already solved in your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34510274/1983854). What you may need is to use a new awk, because this error wouldn't happen in a new one.

Comment: What triplee solved worked. I just thought that error appeared due to some flaw of logic in the code, not an outdated awk version. As i said, i m still entirely new to awk.

Comment: @onlyf yes, my impression is that there is either of these problems: 1) the file has some strange format, so that every line gets mangled together to form a huge line, or 2) your awk version is very old. What system are you working on? Installing GNU awk shouldn't be complicated.